# Tracking file state while editing files with Desktop.getDesktop().edit(File file)

Tags: java, desktop, state, tracking, edit

Is it somehow possible to keep track of the current file state when opening/editing a file by calling `Desktop.getDesktop().edit(File myFile)`?

My goal is to lock a shared file (which is stored in a common database) while one of many users is editing the file and finally when he saves the changes to the file I get some kind of "event" so that I can unlock the file again as soon as he closed the corresponding application resp. file.

Any help highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive notifications about filesystem changes you use a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) (since Java 7).

You register a service and watch for `ENTRY_MODIFY` event type.

Nice walk-through is available here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

If you can't use Java 7 you should look at [jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Hi Qwe - that was exactly the thing I was watching out for - Many, many thanks for the link!